# flash player (video) doesn't load in selenium chrome webdriver

Tags: flash, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

I am using selenium and xvfb to headlessly visit a webpage with google chromes webdriver (using google chrome, not chromium).

The webpage has a flash iframe with a video in it. When I go to the page, everything loads properly except for the video.

1. Is Flash not supported by googles webdriver?
2. How can flash be enabled ?

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chrome/driver')
```

I followed this setup: https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/, except I installed the latest ChromeDriver 2.24, not 2.20.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to install the Flash Player from [the Adobe website](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) and it worked for me. Even though Pepper flash is already installed on Chrome.